# Query For All Array Matches in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a feeling this may have been asked elsewhere, but am having a tough time finding an answer.

Basically, I have a MongoDB/Mongoose Schema that stores a list of registered users. I am building a GUI that can query for all records that meet certain conditions. In this case, I am wanting to let the GUI users select via checkboxes all the genders they'd like to include in the query.

If I were passing in just a string, I know I'd write it as follows:

```
    User.find({"gender": gender}).exec(function(err, users){
        if(err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json(users);
    });
```

But since I'll possibly be passing in an array of options, is there a native Mongoose function I can use to query the following cases?

```
[Male]
[Male, Female, Other]
[Male, Other]
[Female]
etc.
```

What would be the best way to write this query in Mongoose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `$in` operator

```
  var gender = [Male, Female, Other]
  User.find({"gender": {$in: gender}})
```

Comment: You rock. I figured it was something simple. Thanks.